# full text searching not working in multiple colomn

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `frontCover`, `type`, `category`, `user`, `author`, `MRP`, `sellingPrice`, `isNew`, `isRaw`, `binding`, `publisherName`, `publicationYear`, (MATCH name,author AGAINST ("made easy editorial board" IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AS relevance FROM `books` WHERE LOWER(type) = 'college' AND (MATCH name,author AGAINST ('made easy editorial board' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```

when trying to run query it gives me error

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I have added name and author full text Indexes.
but when i run single column it works. i need to get from two column matching result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a combined FULLTEXT index on both columns as you are using both columns in the query.

```
ALTER TABLE `books` 
ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `IDX_FULLTEXT_NAME_AUTHOR` (`name` ASC, `author` ASC);
```

Comment: does it effect my existing data in table?

Comment: It shouldn't affect your existing data.